# MySQL create function dfficulties

Tags: mysql

Okay, so this is my first time attempting to `CREATE FUNCTION`, so please bear with me!

So, I have this (simplified) table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `pokemon` (
    `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `userid` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `boxid` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 255,
    `boxpos` SMALLINT UNSIGNED,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `position` (`userid`,`boxid`,`boxpos`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

I want to create a function that, given a user ID and box ID, returns an empty box position (ie. one that won't trigger a duplicate key error).

Note that `boxid` uses values from 0 to 249 for box IDs, and 255 as a special value for the user's Party. `boxpos` can range from 0 to 45,504 in Boxes, but only 0 through 5 in the Party. Also, in the Party the returned position should be the first empty one, whereas in a Box it should be a random position.

So, with all this in mind, here was my attempt:

```
begin
declare ret smallint unsigned;
declare exist tinyint unsigned default 1;
if fieldid = 255 then
  create temporary table `party` (
    `pos` smallint unsigned not null
  );
  insert into `party` values (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5);
  delete from `party` where `pos` in (select `fieldpos` from `pokemon` where `userid`=userid and `fieldid`=255);
  select `pos` into ret from `party` limit 1;
  if ret is null then select `[[Error: No room in Party]]` from `party`; end if;
else
  while exist=1 do
    set exist=0;
    set ret=floor(rand()*45504);
    select 1 into exist from `pokemon` where `fieldid`=fieldid and `userid`=userid and `fieldpos`=ret;
  end while;
end if;
return ret;
end;
```

*(Note that this is the body of the function, as entered into phpMyAdmin)*

EDIT: I've fixed the `DECLARE` problem, but now it's saying I can't return a result set from a function.

I'm unsure where I've gone wrong, and I think I need help getting on the right track. In particular, have I got the function logic right in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

```
if ret is null then select `[[Error: No room in Party]]` from `party`; end if;
```

you select a constant value for all rows from the `party` table but don't put the result of that select into a variable. That's probably where the error comes from.

It should probably be something like:

```
if ret is null then 
   set ret = '[[Error: No room in Party]]';
end if;
```

(Also note that String literals need to be enclosed in single quotes (`'`), not with those dreaded backticks - which aren't necessary in the first place, so it's better to leave them out alltogether).

Comment: The point of that line is to throw an error, since I'm using a version of MySQL prior to 5.5. I need the function to interrupt the query being run if there is no room in the Party.

Comment: @Kolink: Doesn't MySQL support throwing exceptions?

Comment: @Kolink: that's lame (but I'm not really surprised...). Maybe you can execute dynamic SQL that is invalid (using `PREPARE`) so that the SQL is not checked when creating the procedure.

Comment: I was able to fix it by adding `into exist`. That way the query result is being put in a variable.